# How can I stop the whole code inside a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, asynchronous, async-await

I am using selenium and threading, and I have a funcion `check_browser_running` to check if the browser is still running or not:

```py
def check_browser_running()
  while True:
    try:
      driver.title
    except WebDriverException:
      print("DRIVER WAS CLOSED")
```

then I run this function in a thread to let other code running:

```py
th = threading.Thread(target=check_browser_running)
th.start()
```

Last thing is, I have a loop function to stop the code from running, because if any error happened in my code, I want the code to stop instead of exiting:

```py
def stop():
  while True:
    pass
```

What I want is that how can I stop the code from running using the `stop()` function through a function that is running a thread?? Because if I called `stop()` in a thread this will not stop the main code.

Comment: You can use a global variable which can be set from within the thread. You would then test that from time to time in the main program. If that's not appropriate, you might want to research Events and/or signals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can do something like this: (Recommended)

```
import threading

running = True

def thread():
    global running

    while running:
        if(some_event):
            stop()

def stop():
    global running

    running = False

th = threading.Thread(target=thread)
th.start()
```

Where you run a while loop with a variable as a flag you can set to false. To end the loop.

Or a tackier solution where you just get the pid of the python program and kill it.

```
import os, signal

def stop():
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)
```

Which will kill the entire program regardless if you call it from withing a thread.

Comment: Recommended? By whom?

Comment: Myself and whoever answered this question for me. (I don't remember who exactly)
Both solutions work just fine. But the first one looks more professional in my opinion.

Comment: In the *thread()* function you call another function to set *running = False* then the *while* loop will break. Why not just *break* when *some_event* occurs. Also, the signal variant will stop the whole program - not just the thread

Comment: Well he did ask to stop the whole program. And changing the running variable doesn't have to happen within that while loop specifically. It was just an easy way to illustrate it.
But yes you are correct in that a break would work in this situation.